# Can any Java program be deployed to Geronimo

Tags: java, geronimo

I'm working in a lab where they typically deploy apps to Geronimo.  I have an existing stand-alone server based app written in Java.  Can any Java application be hosted in Geronimo?  If so, is there a good reference to take an existing app and host it in Geronimo?  Is there a benefit to hosting something in Geronimo or are there times when something is best left as a stand-alone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work on an Application Server, there is **specific way a program should be written** for it to be qualified for deployment on app server. A program can be a Servlet, EJB, JSP etc. If your existing stand-alone server based app is any of these, then it can surely be deployed on Geronimo.

Comment: With some classpath exceptions!!!1 Jokes aside generally speaking Santosh is right but you might find some deployment issues.